# Orthogonal complement propertiss

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

I'm required to prove that $W^{\perp} + U^{\perp} \subseteq (W \cap U)^{\perp}$.
I've already proven $U \subseteq W \to W^{\perp} \subseteq U^{\perp}$ and $(U+W)^{\perp} = W^{\perp} \cap U^{\perp}$.
Plus, I would appreciate an explaination about the difference between $u \in W+U$ and $u \in W \cup U$, I think I might mixing them up in my head :)
Thanks.

Comment: The second of the equalities you have supposedly proven is wrong. Typo?

Comment: $u \in W + U$ means that $u$ is the sum of an element of $W$ with an element of $U$, whereas $u \in W \cap U$ means that $u$ is an element of $W$ and an element of $U$ at the same time.

Comment: @darijgrinberg fixed it, and fixed my other question as well, I meant $u \in W \cup U$

Comment: @user114138 For example, the union of two (different) lines is, well, two lines (not even a linear subspace). Ths $sum$ of two lines is a plane, which is much different.

Comment: @GPerez That's how I initially thought of that, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x\in W+U$ means there exist $w\in W$ and $u\in U$ such that $x=w+u$. (Note that the pair $(w,u)$ doesn't have to be unique here.) On the other hand, $x\in W\cup U$ means that $x\in W$ or $x\in U$ (or both).

This problem is an excellent example of one where you should do the "obvious" expansions of definitions before trying to think hard. (Tim Gowers has some excellent blog posts about this.) Of course it takes some practice to learn what the "obvious" steps are; so let's practice on this one.

Statement to be proved:
$$
W^\perp + U^\perp \subseteq (W\cap U)^\perp
$$
By the definition of $\subseteq$, this is the same statement as
$$
\text{if } x \in W^\perp + U^\perp \text{, then } x \in (W\cap U)^\perp
$$
By the definition of a sum of subspaces (as given above), this is equivalent to
$$
\text{if there exist } y \in W^\perp \text{ and } z\in U^\perp \text{ such that } x=y+z \text{, then } x \in (W\cap U)^\perp
$$
Finally, by the definition of (subspace)${}^\perp$, we see that an equivalent staement is
$$
\text{if there exist } y \in W^\perp \text{ and } z\in U^\perp \text{ such that } x=y+z \text{, then } x \perp v \text{ for every } v \in W\cap U.
$$
(Here I'm using $x\perp v$ to mean $\langle x,v\rangle=0$.)

All we've done so far is expand the definitions of the various pieces of notation. Now it's time to think: can we  prove this last statement? I'll leave this to you, after noting that the variable $x$ is kind of redundant: we could just as well prove
$$
\text{if } y \in W^\perp \text{ and } z\in U^\perp \text{, then } (y+z) \perp v \text{ for every } v \in W\cap U.
$$

Comment: It's very nice when you can just prove by "expanding definitions". Any link to said blog posts?

Comment: Let $u+w \in U^{\perp}+W^{\perp}$ and let $v \in (W \cap U)$, so $<u+w,v> = <u,v>+<w,v> = 0+0=0$ which means $u+w \in (W \cap U)^{\perp}$ because $(u+v) \perp v$ for all $v \in (W \cap U)$. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

First note that what you've proven already: $$U \subseteq W \Longrightarrow W^{\perp} \subseteq U^{\perp}$$
Can be turned into: $$\quad\quad U\subseteq W \iff W^{\perp} \subseteq U^{\perp} \quad\text{(1)}$$
Once you prove that $$\quad\quad\quad\quad\,\,\,\,\,(L^{\perp})^{\perp} = L \quad\quad\quad\quad \text{(2)}
$$
But I'll leave that to you. Now, starting with the statement you want to prove: $$W^{\perp} + U^{\perp} \subseteq (W \cap U)^{\perp}\stackrel{\text{(1)}}{\iff}  (\,\,(W \cap U)^{\perp})^{\perp}\subseteq (W^{\perp} + U^{\perp})^{\perp}\stackrel{\text{(2)}}{\iff}W\cap U\subseteq W\cap U $$

which is true, so the original statement is also true.

Note: I've also used your formula for the orthogonal complement of the sum.

Comment: As far as we've told $(L^{\perp})^{\perp} = L$ only when $L$ is finite which wasn't assumed in this "Lemma". I've used it though to prove $W^{\perp} + U^{\perp} = (W \cap U)^{\perp}$ when $V$ is finite $(U,W \subseteq V)$.

Comment: @user114138 Ah. Sorry, I'm used to the [linear-algebra] tag dealing with finite dimension. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$W \cup U$ may not be a subspace, while $W + U$ is a subspace. Actually it is the smallest subspace which contain $W \cup U$.

$x \in W^{\perp} + U^{\perp} \Rightarrow x = w' + u'$, where $w' \in W^{\perp}$ and $u' \in U ^{\perp}$. This means that for every $w \in W$ and $u \in U$ we have $\langle w,w'\rangle = 0$ and $\langle u, u' \rangle = 0$. Let $y \in W \cap U$, then $\langle y, w' \rangle = 0$ and $\langle y, u' \rangle = 0$. So $\langle y, x \rangle = \langle y, w' + u' \rangle = \langle y, w' \rangle + \langle y, u' \rangle = 0$ (thanks to the distributivity law), which proves that $x \in (W \cap U)^{\perp}$.